# regex expression to check if same number of repetions in python

Tags: python, regex

I have two complex (and maybe repeating) groups (ab) and (cd)

abcd is valid
abababcdcdcd is valid

but:
ababcd is invalid
abcdcd is invalid

my idea is to repeat with |:
`((ab){1}(cd){1})|((ab){2}(cd){2})|((ab){3}(cd){3})|((ab){4}(cd){4})` and so on

I want to know if exists an effective way to write this expression.

Comment: Could you specify whether "" or "abcd" shall be the shortest valid match, so I can make my answer more lean ;)

Comment: 'abcd' but I want to recurr only a part of entire regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive expression, for instance,

```py
import regex

# example:
example_string = "ababababcdcdcdcd"

# regular expression that consumes the whole string
regex.match(r"^(ab(?1)cd|abcd)$", example_string)
```

If you want to match the expression as substring (not consuming the whole string), you can go without `^` and `$`, i.e. `"(ab(?R)cd|abcd)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I want to recurr only on local part delimited by paranthesis. To explain better, I have composed a string like: y(ab(?R)cd)x. I want y and x to not repeat

Comment: In principal, you can recur local parts by regex-recursion, but I don't get your requirement. Maybe you can give a false-positive or false-negative example for my proposal? In any case, you could specify a bit better in your questions what you want :)

Comment: To respond to your comment, `r"^y(ab(?1)cd|abcd)x$"`? A bit too much guessing here :D

Comment: I am curious what library do you use because re is not recognising extension:
re.error: unknown extension ?1 at position 6

Comment: As the import shows, it is `regex`. To my knowledge, `re` does not support recursive expressions. As your title states `regex`, I considered that a valid choice. You can install `regex` via `pip`, for instance.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not sharing a link :)

Answer (score -2):

In this case there is a way but only tailor made to suit the requirement.

Critical assumptions

- String has a block of only two substrings "ab" and "cd"
- All occurrences of repeated "ab" and "cd" are separately clustered
- "cd" always comes after "ab"

If that is true, then below code will work. Not very elegant. Wait for masters to give a better solution.

```py
def CheckValid(String):
    Split_1 = String.split("ab")
    LeftStringCount = len(Split_1[:-1])
    RightStringCount = len(Split_1[-1].split("cd"))-1 ## -1 to account for the extra blank in the result
    if LeftStringCount == RightStringCount:
        print("Valid string")
    else:
        print("Invalid string")
        

CheckValid("abababcdcdcd")
CheckValid("abcd")
CheckValid("abcdcd")
CheckValid("ababcd")
```

Gives the following output.

```py
Valid string
Valid string
Invalid string
Invalid string
```